# Expectation of Sn, the random time at which nth failure occurs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The failure times of machines can be modeled by a Poisson process $(N_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ with
some rate $\lambda$ > 0. On average, there are three failures per unit of time.

Let the successive failure times by $S_1<S_2<...$ That is, for each n $\geq$ 1, $S_n$ is
the random time at which the $n^{th}$ failure occurs. In addition, we let $S_0 = 0$. It can be
proved (you are not requested to do it) that for all n $\geq$ 1, ($S_{n} - S_{n-1}$) has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$: using this property, compute the expectation of $S_n$

==============

So, ($S_{n} - S_{n-1}$) ~ exp($\lambda$) then the expectation would be $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

$N_{t}$ has Poisson distribution but the distribution of $S_{n}$ is unknown. By using the linearity of expectation:

$E(S_{n} - S_{n-1})=E(S_{n})-E(S_{n-1})$

$\frac{1}{\lambda}=E(S_{n})-E(S_{n-1})$

Then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

$E(S_n) = [E(S_n)-E(S_{n-1})]+[E(S_{n-1})-E(S_{n-2})]+...+[E(S_2)-E(S_1)]+E(S_1)$.

And you know the value of each bracketed expression (as well as $E(S_1)$).